# NullPointerException is thrown on second method when using dependsOnMethods TestNG attribute with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, exception

```
package testNG;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class TestNGUsingFacebook {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void openBrowser() {

        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://wwww.facebook.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "openBrowser" })
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Neenad");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to run this sample code, I receive a null pointer exception as follows:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testNG.TestNGUsingFacebook.openBrowser(TestNGUsingFacebook.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
PASSED: openBrowser
FAILED: loginToFacebook
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testNG.TestNGUsingFacebook.loginToFacebook(TestNGUsingFacebook.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I have tried commenting the second function, but still Google Chrome does not open.

Comment: this is not how you setup browsers for your tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears, though you are setting the property for the chrome driver through

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

You are not initializing the driver instance before using it like : `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

So please add the following line as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); // Setting the chrome driver property
driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Inializing the chrome driver
```

`driver` is the declared `WebDriver` instance in your above code.

Answer (score 1):

There is one small mistake you made, You have forget to initiate the instance of `webdriver`. This is the reason why you found the `null pointer exception`.

> As your project is in Java Based, So require to follow java code standards and formats as well.

Here is the correct code :

```
@Test
 public void openBrowser() {

try {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); // just add this line
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://wwww.facebook.com");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You miss to instantiate the **WebDriver**. Add `driver = new ChromeDriver();` in code after `setProperty()`, Rest is fine

```
try {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();  
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://wwww.facebook.com");
       } 
catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
       }
```